# Keep the text of the text box through a PageLoad();

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am wondering How i can keep the text of my textbox even if i have to make a new page load, clicking on an hyperlink.

It's always an empty string.

Can someone help me ?

```
            lkForgotten.NavigateUrl = string.Format("Logon.aspx?forgotten={0}", "");
            lkSend.NavigateUrl = string.Format("Logon.aspx?forgotten={0}&userEmail={1}", "submited", txtForgotten.Text);

            try
            {
                if (Request.QueryString["forgotten"].ToString() == "")
                {
                    txtForgotten.Visible = true;
                    lkSend.Visible = true;
                }

                if (Request.QueryString["forgotten"].ToString() == "submited")
                {
                    userEmail = txtForgotten.Text;
                    SendForgottenPassword(userEmail);
                }
            }
            catch { }
```

Comment: HTML and web applications are stateless, you can't save data that is on the page, unless you use cookies or Session.

Comment: is that javascript solution work for you ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

Do the redirection with the

Javascript code

```
function redirect()
{
   var val = document.getElementById('<%= txtForgotten.ClientID %>').value;
   location.href='Logon.aspx?forgotten=submitted&userEmail=' + val ;
}

<input type="button" VALUE="Visit Microsoft" OnClick="redirect();">
```

problem witht he above code is when you are creating the url of forget password on page load at that time textbox value is empty and when do redirection by clicking forget password link its getting empty value only rather what you typed in your code...so to make it work do the redirection using javascript as above or make use of click event that do the redirection for you....

**Org**

following line change like this

```
 if (Request.QueryString["forgotten"].ToString() == "submited")                 {                     
   userEmail = txtForgotten.Text = Request.QueryString["userEmail"].ToString() ;                         
    SendForgottenPassword(userEmail);                
 }
```

so when you are clicking button it get the value of userEmail from the querystring and restore value in you textbox ...this will surely do your task

or

you can make use of other client side mecanisam like cookies to store the value and than retrive it back on page...

serverside option is session variable also helpfull if you want to store the value and retrieve it back.....

Comment: @Emged - when you do postback do it from the javascript rather tahn form the servier side ...I am editing my code asap

Comment: How should I use this javascript ?

Comment: @Emged - pasted my code above you can check i and might be you need to modify the page path so that it get reirect to properpalace

Comment: I'd love to see your mechanism for managing this type of urls spanning across multiple pages. Using urls for this may be good one time solution, but it's a very bad if you're thinking at least in a bit wider context.

Comment: @walther - yes answer is related to small context only ...but i would love to create one link button with the serverside clien and write redierction code in that click event

Answer (score 3):

If you need to persist some data specific to the person, you can use a session. It is precisely the thing you need.

You can set it whenever you want and get the values you need.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

**Edit:**
To satisfy some objections raised in comments, if the session itself isn't enough, you can still use a different approach. Monitor the textboxes with javascript and if their value is changed, add a cookie (or add a value to existing cookie, depends on the needs). Still much better approach than using querystring for this type of functionality... At least in my opinion.

Comment: -1 : well session is not going to help untill you create serverside click event because when pressing the link button it get redirect to page rather than taking value of textbox so this wont work over here ...read my answer why its not working...

Comment: @PranayRana, well, that depends on the situation. Either way, using querystring for this type of situation is quite bad in my opinion. Why? Because if you have 20 textboxes (which is still quite a low quantity) and you want to preserve all the values, you'd end up with a very ugly url. Not talking about the situation you have multiple anchor links and want the same functionality for the whole site. Very bad thing to do. You'd have to manage urls for every link and that is really bad. Thanks for the minus tho...